# searching zipcode works online but not offline (from local database)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

the input field in form takes zipcode.. it zipcode matches it shows tick mark. The problem is when i fill the zip code online, it shows tick mark like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lh3k.png (sorry , i was unable attach image here in stackoverflow)

but while doing the same offline (i'm using wamp server) it keeps on searching..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX000.png

the zipcode is already stored in my local mysql database table but i couldnt find out why its not working. i was given this work to find it out but i failed.

Comment: Too little information. Give us something more to be able to even begin to understand

Comment: What is the response of the ajax? Console log errors, script takes to long, errors on the php side and when you want to parse the json(I expect) then it will crash (the js)

Comment: What do you mean under "offline"? Does it means that your wamp server is turned off? Or simply working with local server?

Comment: You script seems not able to connect to local database. Check your DB connection.

Comment: Install fire bug extension for mozilla , and see the console tab's error list...!

Comment: i mean working with local server. please find the code in this link
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1372253/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u said u r working on  project by some one else.have you seen the configuration files where the database ussername and password are saved. also the document root, the server  name etc. i mean though you are working on local machine, it may be taking the reference files from the internet or yourwebste.com so search again and test the config files. also see for any error in fire bug. see the console.log output.